# Apache webserver start fail - WebLogicCluster takes one argument, Defines a list of WebLogic Clusters

Tags: apache, weblogic

This line of apache webserver config restrict it from normal start

`WebLogicCluster localhost:7011, localhost:7012`

Error is:

> WebLogicCluster takes one argument, Defines a list of WebLogic Clusters

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with space.
Right configuration is:

`WebLogicCluster localhost:7011,localhost:7012`